# Cannot connect to local db SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

I'm having an issue with SQL Server. I have Visual Studio 2013. I've checked and can see "SQL Server (SQLEXPRESS)" started in services. I've tried to connect to SQL Server is good, but I tried to connect to Local db I have this issue:

> A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to   SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: Sql Network InterFace, error: 50 - Local Database Runtime error occurred.Error occurred during LocalDb instance startup:Sql Server process failed to start)

Everything happens on the local machine

Comment: Depending on how you are trying to connect, you will likely have to run SQL Server Configuration manager to allow connection types like "Named Pipes", "TCP/IP", etc., for this instance.  If you are connecting with integrated security, it should work as-is

Comment: I am connecting with integrated security

Comment: Did you install this or was it imaged onto your machine?